# Hidden service hostname change

Tags: development

I'm testing Silvertunnel-NG lib. I want to have a server that accepts connections and a client in the same application.

At this moment, I'm trying to connect to my own hidden service created by Silvertunnel-NG lib. I can do it, but my hostname change in every execution. I can connect but first I have to create a new hidden service, I can't use an onion address created in other execution.

This is my test code:

```
public static void setHiddenService(File dir, TorNetLayerUtil tNLU) throws IOException {
    // Create new private+public hidden service key
    TorHiddenServicePrivateNetAddress tHSPNA = tNLU.createNewTorHiddenServicePrivateNetAddress();

    // write new private+public hidden service key to directory
    dir.mkdir();
    tNLU.writeTorHiddenServicePrivateNetAddressToFiles(dir, tHSPNA);
}

public static TorHiddenServicePortPrivateNetAddress readHiddenService(File dir, TorNetLayerUtil tNLU, int port) throws IOException {
    TorHiddenServicePrivateNetAddress netAddress = tNLU.readTorHiddenServicePrivateNetAddressFromFiles(dir, true);
    return new TorHiddenServicePortPrivateNetAddress(netAddress, port);
}

public static void setUp() {
    System.setProperty(TorConfig.SYSTEMPROPERTY_TOR_MINIMUM_ROUTE_LENGTH, "2");
    System.setProperty(TorConfig.SYSTEMPROPERTY_TOR_MAXIMUM_ROUTE_LENGTH, "2");
    System.setProperty(TorConfig.SYSTEMPROPERTY_TOR_MINIMUM_IDLE_CIRCUITS, "2");
    TorConfig.reloadConfigFromProperties();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    setUp(); // setup TOR for tests

    TorNetLayerUtil tNLU = TorNetLayerUtil.getInstance();
    File dir = new File("/key/"); // directory of hostname file
    setHiddenService(dir, tNLU); // create a new hidden service

    TorHiddenServicePortPrivateNetAddress netAddress = readHiddenService(dir, tNLU, 80);

    // get TorNetLayer instance and wait until it is ready
    NetLayer netLayer = NetFactory.getInstance().getNetLayerById(NetLayerIDs.TOR);
    netLayer.waitUntilReady();

    TorNetServerSocket netServerSocket = (TorNetServerSocket) netLayer.createNetServerSocket(null, netAddress);

    ...
```

If i comment "setHiddenService(dir, tNLU);" there are a connection problem, because my hostname have changed.

Can someone tell me what is going on?

Lib: Silvertunnel-NG 0.0.4.

Update: I have created a new method to get hidden service from a private_key file.

```
public static TorHiddenServicePrivateNetAddress createHiddenServiceFromPrivKey(File pkfile, TorNetLayerUtil tNLU) throws IOException{
    final String privateKeyPEMStr = FileUtil.readFile(pkfile);
    final TorHiddenServicePrivateNetAddress netAddressWithoutPort = tNLU.parseTorHiddenServicePrivateNetAddressFromStrings(privateKeyPEMStr, null, false);

    return netAddressWithoutPort;
}
```

**Update**: I recommend to use Stem (Python based) in order to control TOR. Works better.

Comment: Just to throwing this out there, that library has some serious problems. For example, it doesn't appear to use Entry Guards (I don't know java *that* well but from my reading of how it builds circuits that's what it looks like), which makes you far more vulnerable to anyone trying to deanonymize Tor users. For reference of why they're important: https://blog.torproject.org/blog/improving-tors-anonymity-changing-guard-parameters

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a *pre-generated* key for your hidden service, or it will be considered as an *ephimerial*, i.e. it exists only until restart. This is the default behaviour, so if you want to have a static hidden service name - no problem! Pre-generate your key and supply it as an argument to your code for creating the service: it's an optional argument in the call.

Comment: Oh! Didn't see that parameter. Thanks for the answer. I will try it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see where I have to put this parameter. The method "createNewTorHiddenServicePrivateNetAddress" don't have any parameters. When I use "readHiddenService" I get exactly what I want, but it's seems like hidden service don't start. I get "java.io.IOException: connectToHiddenService(): couldn't connect to an introduction point of ..." error.

Comment: @WDay actually, it's in the [Tor control protocol specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt) `ADD_ONION` method.

Comment: It looks like this library acts as Tor, it's not using `ADD_ONION` or interfacing with the control port. It's a java OR/OP implementation.

Comment: @WDay you better try to generate a key file *using tor binary* and load it explicitly in your code. This I have understood from the docs. Please try it and let's see if it works

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin I try it but didn't work. I use the private key from an execution. I will add to the first post a new method to get hidden service from private_key file.

Comment: @WDay actually, your service key can be pre-generated and stored right inside your source code, so for a quick test try to use just a string inside a code, containing the key. And have you tried the tor binary as a key generator? It will ensure that the key is 101% correctly generated one

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin if key and hostname was incorrect the hidden service never start. The key work if I created a new HiddenService inside the code, but it don't work if I try to use a pregenerated key to the service. It's like the hidden service never start or tor don't work. I don't know.

Comment: @WDay pretty *weird*, btw! I'd rather understand that if it was not unable to generate key "on-flight" but could start with a pre-made one. Can you compare the files with the ones generated by Tor? They must be similar btw

Comment: @WDay take a look [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/silvertunnel-ng/wiki/Netlib%20Direct%20API%20Usage/) and try to use the most recent source-compiled lib, i.e. from [their Git repo](https://sourceforge.net/p/silvertunnel-ng/code/ci/master/tree/) just clone it and try - it's a Wiki example, so it is **obliged** to be working with the most recent code

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin at this moment I think I give up. I'm trying to do that using SOCKS5 in Java. I read this page like 1000 times xD I don't know why is not working. Thanks for your answers and I will try with 0.0.5 snapshot or lastest build.

Comment: @WDay take a look at their Git - it's a pre-0.0.6, and you're using 0.0.4 and I bet that you've just downloaded a JAR. Build it all from source - give it a try!

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin yes, I download a .jar and I include it into a project. This is my first "big" project, before this I only write simply applications in Java using one or two imports. At this moment, I see Silvertunnel use Maven, so I'm learning about it and building myself. If I found a solution for the problem I will post it.

Comment: @WDay do you need help with building the library from Git? I'll be glad to help if you need it. It seems for me it's an old bug being hit

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin thanks. I think is not a real problem. Download the source from the git repository, open from an IDE (NetBeans in my case) and Build it, right?

Comment: @WDay Yes. You're using a Git plugin to import a master branch right into your project for a library. The very same sequence for it's dependencies, and - don't forget to put a projects' subdependencies in their properties: it will enable you a *literally* one-click build from source for your library *and all it's dependencies* in the right order. I used to think that JAR's are "safe to just drop into CLASSPATH". Especially working with JRockit I've learned that this is wrong: you better build it **all** form source in your particular environment. It's a glitch-safe approach

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin thanks for all your replies. Now I'm using Stem (Python based control protocol for TOR) and it work like I want.